# using PXUIEnabled attribute on a PXButton

Tags: acumatica

Page: AR303000
Version: 19.200.0081

Good day, is it possible to use the PXUIEnabled with a PXButton?

```
    public PXAction<PX.Objects.AR.Customer> DoWork;
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sync From Parent")]
    [PXUIEnabled(typeof(  Where<Shipment_documents.acccd, Equal<Current<Customer.acctCD>>>))]
    protected void doWork(){}
```

I want the button to disable when the current customer has a document linked to it.

If it not possible what is the best way/practice of accomplishing this at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would override the Customer's RowSelected event and check the results of the query. Give this a try, I don't have the DAC to test against.

```
protected virtual void Customer_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected del)
{
    del?.Invoke(cache, e); //invoke base method first if exists    
    Customer row = (Customer)e.Row;    
    if (row == null)
        return;

    var ShipmentDocuments = PXSelect<Shipment_documents, Where<Shipment_documents.acccd, Equal<Required<Shipment_documents.acccd>>>>.Select(Base, row.AcctCD);
    DoWork.SetEnabled(ShipmentDocuments.Count == 0); //enabled = true when there are no documents
}
```